# Windows won't open from Mac Dock

Tags: macos, mail.app, iterm

I use iTerm a lot and keep the app in the dock. When I first start iTerm, it brings up a terminal window.

If I minimize its window I expect to be able to click on iTerm in dock to bring the iTerm window back into view. But this doesn't always happen. Often it doesn't reopen the window. I'll try clicking on the icon several times but it never opens the window. If I right-click on the dock icon it'll list the open windows. I can select one but it still won't open.

This happen with other apps too. In Messages or Mail, when this happens, I'm forced to select a new message window to get a new window. I'm running High Sierra, 10.13.5 on my iMac. I've tried restarting normal and restarting in safe mod but nothing works. Does anyone have a clue of why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

These might help. Not known for sure.

**Method 1** :

1. Go to **~/Library/Preferences**.
2. Take a backup of the **com.googlecode.iterm2.plist** file.
3. Delete it from Preferences folder.
4. Restart iTerm.
5. Maybe it gets fixed. Else put back the backup file in the same folder.

Note: You may not need backup if you wish you may not need the user settings.

**Method 2** :

1. Close the windows.
2. Right click and unselect **Options** -> **Keep in Dock**.
3. Restart iTerm from **Applications** folder.
4. Select **Options** -> **Keep in Dock**.

My References : [Mail not opening issue in Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6702771), [Details regarding .plist files](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1869002), [Similar issue in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/360133/clicking-on-dock-icon-does-not-bring-window-on-top-os-x-lion)

Comment: It looks like Method 1 might be working. I have to give it more time to find out for sure.  If it is working i'll be sure to accept your answer.  thanks.

Comment: @jmh Is the method working ?

Comment: no sorry. it didn't work.